# How to show an entire line that has equal cells to another line?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Frequently  I analyze some registers of births like this:

[image]

The problem is that registers 8 and 9 are probably twins (born at same place, same day with a mother with same age) but were not registered as it. 
I have thousands of lines and I would like to identify this kind of problem automatically.

I do not know how to start.. COUNTIF? VLOOKUP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in D2 and Copy down:

```
=(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,C2)=1)+1
```

If the count is greater than one it will return `1` if it equals 1 then it will return `2`

[image]